# Impossible to access http://mvnrepository.com/

Tags: jenkins, wget

I am suddenly getting this error in Jenkins:

```
= Check pre-requisite

Checking global pre-requisite

- aws is reachable in PATH [  OK  ]

DEBUG : wget --spider -S -qO-  http://mvnrepository.com/
      HTTP/1.1 308 Permanent Redirect
      Content-Length: 0
      Date: Tue, 02 Oct 2018 04:49:58 GMT
      Location: https://mvnrepository.com/
      Server: nginx/1.10.1
      Connection: keep-alive
      X-RBT-SCAR: 88888:59701061:1000 ADL
      HTTP/1.1 308 Permanent Redirect
      Content-Length: 0
      Date: Tue, 02 Oct 2018 04:49:58 GMT
      Location: https://mvnrepository.com/
      Server: nginx/1.10.1
      Connection: keep-alive
      X-RBT-SCAR: 10.195.254.60:59701066:1000 ADL
     - http://mvnrepository.com/ is reached [FAILED]
   Impossible to access http://mvnrepository.com/ (wget error code 8 : Server issued an error response )
       # Error detected 



    ###############################################################################
    End of Checks. Status =
    - No warning detected
    - Error detected while executing checks. Unless -ignore-checks flag is on, those will block the installation process and prevent we move further until those are solved.
    ########################################################################
    # Error : Prerequiste check ./project_files/bin/check_prerequisite is not ok. Stopping the operation.
    ########################################################################
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like that site has stopped supporting HTTP and are telling you to use HTTPS instead. In the redirect information, you can see

```
Location: https://mvnrepository.com/
```

So, use HTTPS and you should be fine. More specifically, use

```
wget --spider -S -qO-  https://mvnrepository.com/
```